# Node.js: Regular Expressions to Parse 'Content-Type'

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Given the text below:

```
 --2vEsE.4eBcGncL7.1Tvsnl.7yygwPC
content-type: text/plain;
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

XXXX

--2vEsE.4eBcGncL7.1Tvsnl.7yygwPC
content-type: message/delivery-status

YYYYY

--2vEsE.4eBcGncL7.1Tvsnl.7yygwPC
content-type: message/rfc822

ZZZZZ

--2vEsE.4eBcGncL7.1Tvsnl.7yygwPC--
```

What's the best way to get a new string with the text "XXXX" and another for "YYYYY" and "ZZZZZ"? That text is every changing, what I need is to get to the position between one content-type and the other content-type.

Thanks

Comment: May XXXX contain content-type?

Comment: Hi, there's little pattern on your text as it is (only '--' is a helpful pattern on this example). How are your XXXX YYYY and ZZZZ defined? Do they contain new lines, '--', spaces..?

Comment: @Felipe, yes. XXX YYY and ZZZZ can be anything. we also have "content-type: " as a pattern.

Comment: The problem is that even tough you have Content-type as a pattern, you still cant make use of it because some times it is followed by charset, some times its not...,

Comment: yea, sorry donald, re-edited my comment

Comment: @Felipe, Can't I write from --2vEsE, to the next --2vEsE to a String?

Comment: What do you mean? Is getting the string between --2vEsE acceptable solution for you?

Comment: Yes it is. That way I can have "XXXX","YYY" and remove the line starting by "Content-type:" in each block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use text.split("--2vEsE") for your solution.

Comment: and then how do I remove the "content-type" ? Do I split again? Thanks

Comment: you can make a replace, something like .replace(/content-type.*/,"") should work